# Get a page's source with PHP, manipulate with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom, html-parsing

JavaScript cannot get an arbitrary page's source code, last I knew. But PHP can pretty easliy.

```
//get page source code with php
<?php

url = 'http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/strong?s=t';
$src = file_get_contents($url);

?>
```

PHP is not good at manipulating the DOM, but jQuery is great for that!

I would like to do something like

```
//manipulate source code with javascript
<script>
html = '"' + <?php echo $src;?> + '"';
listItems = $(html + " li");
printLists = '';
$.each(listItems, function(ind, el) {
    printLists += el.innerHTML + "<br/>";
});

document.write(printLists);

</script>
```

But, any time I echo `$src` into the script tag, it gets interpreted as HTML immediately and the page becomes a live mockery of the actual site.

```
//Actually just shows me thesaurus.com@strong
<body>
    <div id="holder" style="display: none;"></div>

<script>
    holder = $("#holder");
    nodeNames = [];
    html = $.parseHTML(<?php echo $src;?>, holder, false);
</script>
</body>
```

The phrase 'virtual DOM' sounds right, though I really don't want any of the copied source code to show up at all. I just want to extract certain parts of it : to run a script from the console, search a few thesaurus sites for a term, take the results, and save them to JSON accessed by a local thesaurus script.

I have a solid idea of how to do everything else, didn't expect this to be the tricky part!

Any suggestions on preventing the browser from parsing HTML?

(I would prefer this to run just as a script file without a browser anyway, but had trouble loading jQuery in a `thesaurus.js` file.)

Answer (score 0):

You could run a php script to get file contents and echo the results to a textarea with readonly/disabled on, then query that php file through ajax to display the resulting textarea on the page.

For example, output.php:

```
<?php
    $str = '<p>I am a paragraph.</p>';
    echo '<textarea readonly="readonly">'.$str.'</textarea>';
?>
```

AJAX call in the original file:

```
$.ajax({url: 'output.php', success: function(data) { $('#result').html(data); }});
```